# Make sliding div not scrollable

Tags: jquery

I have this code,

```
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        if (jQuery('.totop').hasClass('visible') == false) {
            jQuery('.totop').stop().animate({
            right: '0px'
            }, function () {
            jQuery('.totop').addClass('visible')
        });
    }
} else {
    if (jQuery('.totop').hasClass('visible') == true) {
        jQuery('.totop').stop().animate({
            right: '-2600px'
        }, function () {
            jQuery('.totop').removeClass('visible')
            });
        }
    }
    });
```

it works fine, but i have a responsive site so i get a scroll bar on the bottom of the screen that does not really work for me. How can i remove the bottom scroll bar?

Comment: I think that the slider is some wider then your `viewport`, and the browser is forcing the scrollbar to be shown, so you need to resize it in order to fit it.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer....what do i need to resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i worked out by doing overflow-x:hidden to the whole body.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add `overflow: hidden` to the element with the scrollbar. I'd do that using CSS instead of jQuery

Comment: This is the css for my div  .totop {
position: relative;
bottom:80%;
right:-100%;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

Comment: i tried using your overflow:hidden but it does nothing.

Comment: overflow-x:hidden on the body tag on the css did it for me, thanks

Comment: Are you adding that to the correct element? (The overflow attribute) because it should definitely remove the scroll bars